# Wird with additional "s"

Tags: verb

> Wenn wir uns den Arzt leisten können, **wirds** spätestens beim Medikament knapp.

This sentence is from reddit comment section. could you explain the verb "wirds" I see it first time with additional "s". I think there is no explanation of it in my grammar book

https://www.reddit.com/r/ich_iel/comments/fjgwaa/ichiel/

Answer (score 4):

This is a contraction of “wird es”. It would have been better to spell it “wird’s”.

Comment: Not only better, but correct.